# Check for Non-Linear Relationship between Continuous Independent and Ordinal Dependent Variables

Tags: ordinal-data, nonlinear

Lets say I have age as the independent variable; education (1=college; 2=masters; 3=phd) and employment (1=unemployed; 2=part-time; 3=full-time) are the dependent variables.

If I was trying to check for a non-linear relationship between this single continuous independent variable and multiple ordinal dependent variables, what might be the best options?

What if I added additional independent variables into this model, such as height and age predicting education and employment?

Comment: These are bizarre variables and model specifications. You don't state how age is scaled, e.g., is it an integer or bucketed? Education may be ordinal, your grouping starts with *college* without clarifying whether that is a college *bachelors* level degree, an *associates* degree, some college without any degree, etc. Then, too, it eliminates the possibility that some people may have only a high school diploma and, quite possibly, not even a GED. Employment cannot be made ordinal even with the most generous of assumptions. Finally, testing height as being related to any of these is nonsense.

Comment: @DJohnson - Thanks, you're right. This example has nothing to do with the real study. It's just meant to give a reasonable parallel to allow others to comment on a direction for modeling techniques that could be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should should take a look at splines or fractional polynomials. A link that could help you : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2477199/